# StringTemplate : how to import from a jar?

Tags: import, stringtemplate-4

I have a case where I am loading a string template group from a file contained in a jar.
This works fine using the following mechanism:

```
final String urlName = new StringBuilder()
            .append("jar:file:").append(templateJar.getAbsolutePath()).append("!")
            .append(templateFileName).toString();
final URL url;
try {
        url = new URL(urlName);
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new GeneratorException("bad manifest url", ex);
}
final STGroup stg = new STGroupFile(url, "US-ASCII", '<', '>');
```

The difficulty comes in when the template file contains an

```
...
import "../../dataTypeMaps.stg"
...
```

String template fails with the following:

```
can't load group file jar:file:/home/phreed/.m2/repository/edu/vanderbilt/isis/druid/druid-template/2.0.0/druid-template-2.0.0.jar!/template/src/main/java/sponsor/orm/ContractCreator.stg
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such group file: ../../dataTypeMaps.stg
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupFile.<init>(STGroupFile.java:69)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroup.importTemplates(STGroup.java:570)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.GroupParser.group(GroupParser.java:199)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroup.loadGroupFile(STGroup.java:619)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupFile.load(STGroupFile.java:139)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupFile.load(STGroupFile.java:128)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroup.lookupTemplate(STGroup.java:237)
    at org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroup.getInstanceOf(STGroup.java:172)
    at edu.vanderbilt.isis.druid.generator.Generator.build(Generator.java:215)
    at edu.vanderbilt.isis.druid.generator.DruidMojo.execute(DruidMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Is it possible to set things up with the jar so that the import will work?
The above approach works fine when there is no jar involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the path to the imported file is wrong

```
...
import "dataTypeMaps.stg"
...
```

The import will cause the file to be looked for starting at the root of the jar.
The above import would amount to the file being placed at...

```
final String urlName = new StringBuilder()
        .append("jar:file:").append(templateJar.getAbsolutePath()).append("!")
        .append("dataTypeMaps.stg").toString();
```

Why the behavior is different than when the template group file is on the native file system I do not know.
In order to get this to work I changed the classpath to include the jar file.
As this was done in the context of a Maven plugin, the plugin needs to change the classpath dynamically.  This was done with the following code...

```
 public void setTemplateJarName(String templateJarName) throws GeneratorException {
    this.templateJarName = templateJarName;
    final Thread ct = Thread.currentThread();
    final ClassLoader pcl = ct.getContextClassLoader();
    URL[] nurl;
    try {
        nurl = new URL[]{ new URL("file://"+templateJarName) };
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        throw new GeneratorException("could not load template jar", ex);
    }
    final URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(nurl, pcl);
    ct.setContextClassLoader(ucl);
}
```

Comment: The semantics of loading string-template groups is still a bit of a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Double check your templates are really in your jar.
2. Use the following code :

If the templates are dispatched in a tree like this:

```
/-->resources
   +--> c/     (many .st and .stg files)
   +--> cpp/   (many .st and .stg files)
   +--> java/  (many .st and .stg files)
   +--> c.stg
   +--> cpp.stg
   +--> java.stg
```

The content of `java.stg` is:

```
group Java;

import "java"

doNothing() ::= <<>>
```

To load all the files in one call :

```
URL     url   = getClass().getResource( "/resources/" + templateName );
STGroup group = new STGroupFile( url, "utf-8", '<', '>' );
```

In my case `templateName` equals `c.stg`, `cpp.stg` or `java.stg`.

Answer (score 0):

The relative path only works on the file system. If you want to import a template from the classpath, use the fully qualified name. This is the same, as when you would load the file from the classpath yourself, using Class::getResource(). Using the fully qualified name, also works for the filesystem.

So, assuming there are two template files:

- src/main/resources/util/date.stg
- src/main/resources/generator/class.stg

Then in class.stg you use the fully qualified name:

```
import "util/date.stg"
```